# How to solve NoReverse error showing in Detail View with Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a website in which there are cartoons displayed on the home page and when the we click on that cartoon, we get to see the seasons of the particular cartoon, now that is all working fine, but when I want the season to show it's details and episodes associated with when clicked it show me this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /cartoon/3
Reverse for 'episode_list' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['episode_list/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']
```

Here are my files :

**Urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path 
from .views import CartoonListView, CartoonSeasonView, SeasonDetailView


urlpatterns = [
    path('', CartoonListView.as_view(), name="home"),
    #the url that shows the list of cartoon seasons
    path('cartoon/<int:pk>' , CartoonSeasonView.as_view(), name="cartoon"),

    #the url that i want to show the season details as well as the episodes associated with the season
    path('episode_list/<int:pk>' , SeasonDetailView.as_view(), name="episode_list"),
    
 
]
```

**Models.py**

```
# Create your models here.
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Cartoon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cover = models.ImageField()
    description = models.TextField()
    start_date = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    end_date = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 


class CartoonSeason(models.Model):
    cartoon = models.ForeignKey(Cartoon, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    season_cover = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=False)
    season_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    season_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False)
    


    
  
  
    def __str__(self):
        return self.cartoon.name + str(self.season_name)


class Episode(models.Model):
    season = models.ForeignKey(CartoonSeason, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False)
    video = models.FileField( blank=True, null=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from  django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import CartoonSeason, Cartoon, Episode
# Create your views here 

class CartoonListView(ListView):
    model = Cartoon
    template_name = "index.html"



class CartoonSeasonView(DetailView):
  
    model = Cartoon
    template_name = "season.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["seasons"] = CartoonSeason.objects.filter(cartoon=self.object)
        return context



class SeasonDetailView(DetailView):
  
    model = CartoonSeason
    template_name = "episode_list.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["episodes"] = Episode.objects.filter(season=self.object)
        return context
```

**season.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
    test
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <main>
        <section class="cartoon-description">
            <div class="season_head">
                <img src="{{object.cover.url}}" width="260px" alt="">
                <div class="cartoon-name">
                    <h1>{{object.name}}</h1>
                    <small >{{object.start_date}} - {{object.end_date}}</small>
                    <br>
                    <div class="description">
                        <strong>Description:</strong>
                        <br>
                        <p>{{object.description}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </section>

        <hr>

        <section class="season">
            {% for season in seasons%}
                <a href="{% url 'episode_list' episode_list.pk %}">Check</a>
                <div class="season-list">
                   
                    <div class="season-img">
                        <img src="{{season.season_cover.url}}" alt="{{season.season_cover.url}}" width="180px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="season-details">
                        <h1>Season {{season.number}}: {{season.season_name}}</h1>
                        
                        <div class="season-description">
                            <strong>Description:</strong>
                           <p>{{season.season_description}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                   
                </div>
                

            {% endfor %}
        </section>
        
    </main>
{% endblock %}
```

It seems like something really obvious but I don't seem to find so any solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello, you are passing to `url` function `episode_list.pk`. Can you show content of episode_list?

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering
`{% url 'episode_list' episode_list.pk %}`
But the object for CartoonSeason is in `season` template variable. Replace that line with
`{% url 'episode_list' season.pk %}`.

Comment: Knew i was missing something obvious, thank you very much.